# Java safe return type container

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I am a c++ developer by day, and I am used to the convention of const return types. I am aware that there is no facility similar to this in java.

I have a specific situation and was wondering the best immutable collection for my task. In C++ I would just use std::vector.

I have a WavFile class that currently has a float[] data, I would like to replace this with something that could be immutable.

Some important stipulations about the container is that its size is known at creation, and it does not need to dynamically grow or shrink at all. Secondly, it should be O(1) to index into the container.

And most importantly, like the topic alludes to, I want to be able to have a getter that returns an immutable version of this container.

What would be the container type I am looking for? Is this something that is possible in java?

Comment: You need your own container wrapping `float[]` array. Any collection based on Java generics would have too much overhead in terms of amount of storage, and even more overhead in terms of locality of reference. Write your own container that fulfills your requirements. Getter should make a defensive copy of your array for the caller.

Comment: I think the better way to avoid exposing internal data by design.  Instead of exposing the internal data, if your aim is just to let people iterate thru each float, why not simply expose a `DoubleStream getDataStream()` or even a `void forEachDataPoint(DoubleConsumer consumer)`? If you expect people to do some kind of random access, you can also expose something like `float dataPoint(int index); float[] dataPoints(int from, int to);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live with the boxing cost, a [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) or [Guava `ImmutableList`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) will work.

If not, try [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/), which provides [`TFloatArrayList`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TFloatArrayList.html) and [an easy way to make them unmodifiable](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/TCollections.html#unmodifiableCollection(gnu.trove.TFloatCollection)).

Comment: "Secondly, it should be O(1) to index into the container..." - Do any of your suggestions comply?

Comment: @MordechayS – java.util.ArrayList is implemented using an array. We can index in O(1) time... `arrayList.get( /*int index*/ );`

Comment: @wfunston Thanks! So, isn't only the Trove API a valid answer?

Comment: @MordechayS – Trove is not the only answer. In this case, Collections is a class within java's API. [java.util.Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). ArrayList is a subclass (grandchild) of Collections.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it is better to tackle the problem by design.  Returning a collection or the array, even it is `const`, is still unsatisfactory OO design, as you are exposing internal data (although not as bad as exposing it as public member variable).

You may further think of how people are supposed to use the data.

If you expect people to simply iterate through each data point, then you may provide something like

```
public class WaveFile {
    public DoubleStream dataStream() {...}
    public forEachDataPoint(DoubleConsumer consumer) {...}
}
```

If you really want to allow people to do random access, you may provide

```
public class WaveFile {
    public float dataPointAt(int index) {...}
    public DoubleStream dataStream(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {...}
}
```

Such kind of encapsulation avoid a lot of unexpected way of using data, and give you a lot of flexibility on how you represent the data internally.  For example, you may do lazy loading from file on disk, you may make a "WaveFile" for which the data points are generated on the fly by some formula etc.

Comment: Disagree. Is returning a an int through a getter "exposing internal data"? Returning a const vector is fine design. What could go wrong?

Comment: That's actually is a problem, because you still seeing the object as something provide data, instead of something bearing behaviors.  It is not a golden rule that "getter is always wrong", there are cases that is required, for example, as a value object (which really aims at providing data). Using getter/setter, although better than public member var, is still far away from proper encapsulation.

Comment: I guess this famous debate is something OOP developer should know of, and should understand the reasons behind both sides:  http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html

Comment: Well, it may be your choice to not go forward to learn proper OO design idiom and principle and stick with "so-called-OO-but-in-fact-procedural" way of thinking, but I don't think it is appropriate to simply call that "delusional".